# Xpath: Finding the proper xpath with div contain class & data-test-id and text

Tags: selenium, xpath

Want to obtain the xpath for the elements from a drop-down menu (refer the image),

[image]

Tried with the following,

`.//div[@class='styles__dropDownList___1PunQ styles__dropDownList___2fbeV']` with this only the drop down is getting selected

No luck with,

1. `.//div[@class='styles__dropDownList___1PunQ styles__dropDownList___2fbeV' and data-test-id='option_0']`
2. `//div[@class='styles__dropDownList___1PunQ styles__dropDownList___2fbeV' and text()='Hyg']`
3. `//div[@class='styles__dropDownList___1PunQ styles__dropDownList___2fbeV' and contains(@text,'Hyg')]`

Element Section:

```
<div class="dd-menu-items">
   <ul class="dd-items-center">
      <div class="styles__dropDownList___1PunQ styles__dropDownList___2fbeV">
         <div class="styles__optionListItem___1SA75" role="button" data-test-id="option_0" tabindex="0">
            <div class="styles__optionDiv___o55ex">
               <div>Hyg</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="styles__optionListItem___1SA75" role="button" data-test-id="option_1" tabindex="0">
            <div class="styles__optionDiv___o55ex">
               <div>Kay</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="styles__optionListItem___1SA75" role="button" data-test-id="option_2" tabindex="0">
            <div class="styles__optionDiv___o55ex">
               <div>Kay</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="styles__optionListItem___1SA75" role="button" data-test-id="option_3" tabindex="0">
            <div class="styles__optionDiv___o55ex">
               <div>Perio</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="styles__optionListItem___1SA75" role="button" data-test-id="option_4" tabindex="0">
            <div class="styles__optionDiv___o55ex">
               <div>Smiles</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="styles__optionListItem___1SA75" role="button" data-test-id="option_5" tabindex="0">
            <div class="styles__optionDiv___o55ex">
               <div>Smiles</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the link to the page you are working with

Comment: This is an internal application; don't think you will be able to access it

Comment: Why not just using something like //div[contains(text(),'Hyg')]  ?

Comment: What exception you are getting? and What are your code trials and errors?

Comment: Pay attention that when using text attribute you have to use `contains(text(),'Hyg')` and not `contains(@tex,'Hyg')`

Comment: @JyotiPrakashMallick did it help?

Comment: @JyotiPrakashMallick : I hope you have got the answer from other contributor.You can use that as well `//div[text()='Hyg'] `

Comment: You need to click on the dropdown box first and then wait for element to be visible and then use above xpath to click on the item.

Comment: Yeah it worked, thank you so much all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click the desired element you should first open the dropdown box by clicking on it and after that to click on the element.
Since you can select it uniquely only according to the text the element contains you should use `//div[contains(text(),'Hyg')]` or `//div[text()='Hyg']`